# Clear drawings outside of frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have an `UIView` which is drawn on screen with frame (0, 0, 60, 60). All I want is if I change frame to (0, 0, 30, 30) I want the view to be drawn only in it's bounds. How can I clear this frame overlap? I tried `- setNeedsDisplay` on this view but it seems it redraws only new frame and overlap remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I got your question right but it sounds like a bounds-clipping issue.

You may want to experiment with the UIView property `clipsToBounds` on the parent (super-) view.